# Jquery Events and functions just works after a reload (Internet Explorer)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

got a new problem.
I have many jquery functions and events and everything works fine in Firefox.
Now I tried it with Internet Explorer 9 but if I call the site none of my functions are called, I have to reload the site and then it works.
It's a very strange issue could someone help me?

Thanks.

Alex

Comment: Can you supply some code? Kinda hard to tell where the error is based on your describing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of  IE does the actions earlier. That's mean, all actions are fire when the document is not ready yet.

You could try setTimeout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could u please give me an example? Thanks

Comment: Thanks I found the soultion with your help. Instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {...});`
just use this: `jQuery(window).load(function() {...});`
and it works.

Thanks